# If I use two variables to iterate through a 2D array is that still O(n^2) time complexity?

Tags: javascript, big-o

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
  const row = array[i];
  for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j += 1) {
      const el = row[j];
  }
}
```

Would be a typical way to iterate through a 2D array nxn matrix and I'd consider that O(n^2) time complexity.

If I did this instead

```
let count = 0;
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
const n = arr.length;
const max = n * n;

while (count !== max) {
  const ele = arr[i][j];
  if (j === n - 1) {
    j = 0;
    i += 1;
  } else j += 1;
  count += 1;
}
```

Would it still be O(n^2)? Kind of a stupid question, I think the answer is yes, but I just want to double check. Obviously, the first method is much clearer, but then lower time complexity is good as well.

Comment: Yes, your loop still has `max` iterations (with a constant amount of steps in each) where literally `max = n * n`.

Answer (score 0):

Given *n = max(array.length, array[0].length)*:

**Yes** - they are both *O(n^2)*. Even though it's one loop, the number of elements that the `while` loop goes through is the same as the number of elements that the 2 `for` loops go through.

In other words, with the `for` loop you're going through (approximately) *n-sized* chunks *n* times, and with the `while` loop you're going through an *n^2-sized* chunk once.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not *really* O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the first place.

Big-O tells you the worst-case performance of an algorithm by giving an idea of how its time of execution scales with the number of elements handled by the algorithm grows.

In the case of a 2-D matrix, while the matrix is, indeed, square (or, at least, rectangular), it's not really appropriate to use the length of the matrix as `n` here. Rather, you should be using the number of cells in the matrix (`i` x `j`).

A 2-D matrix is, effectively, an array of arrays and your algorithm is simply stepping through each cell once, making it O(n) in both cases. You *could* say that it's O(`i`x`j`), but it's still a linear algorithm.

Comment: *n* is a matter of definition. You can define *n* as *max(i, j)* for convenience and then it's valid to say it's *O(n^2)* (note that *O(i j)* is *O(n^2)* if we define it this way).

Comment: Except `i` and `j` represent different things: rows and columns. The OP's algorithm _is_ a linear sweep through a series of elements and to identify it as an O(n^2) algorithm is to misidentify it. Just because there is a loop within a loop, does not mean that the algorithm is quadratic.

Comment: I think there's no doubt that both algorithms have the same time complexity. The issue is defining *n* and it's perfectly valid to define *n* as one dimension (or max of 2 if it's rectangular) of the array and call resulting complexity *O(n^2)*.

Comment: Again, that's not correct. You're coupling the 2 dimensions when you do that. As your `n` increases, both the number of rows and the number of columns increase... however the implementation clearly shows that the number of rows and columns are _not_ coupled together. You end up artificially making this algorithm seem quadratic because you've artificially made the growth of the elements of the matrix quadratic by tying `i` and `j`. It's clear that if `i` or `j` are fixed, then this is an O(`j`) or O(`i`)

Comment: Agreed, it is more precise to define it in terms of `i` and `j`, but I maintain that it is not invalid to define *n* as one dimension. What if `j` is linearly dependent on `i` in this problem? How do you know?

Comment: @Dancrumb It's more common to gauge matrices by a single dimension, not by the number of its entries. Operations like "get elements in one row" are `O(n)`, not `O(√n)`. This is because matrices of appear in algorithms where one or even both of its dimensions are the size of the input to the solved problem.